# Send captured data from OutputDataReceived back to caller

Tags: c#, events

i have a method that creates a Process calling a console app.

```
double myProcess()
{
    double results;

    Process process = new Process();
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
    process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start(); 
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return results;
}

static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string stringResults = (string)e.Data;
    .
    .
    do some work on stringResults...
    .
    .
    results = stringResults;
}
```

my problem is,how do i send data from process_OutputDataReceived back to myProcess? I cannot use singleton as there are possibilities that this process will be executed in multiple thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a separate method for the `OutputDataReceived` handler; you can use an anonymous method to set the `results` variable directly:

```
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => results = e.Data;
```

(Also, should `results` be `string` or `double`?)

**Edit:** A couple of alternatives for when you need to do more work in the handler:

```
process.OutputDataReceived +=
   (sender, e) =>
   {
        string stringResults = e.Data;
        // do some work on stringResults...
        results = stringResults;
   }

// or

process.OutputDataReceived +=
   delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
        string stringResults = e.Data;
        // do some work on stringResults...
        results = stringResults;
   }
```

Comment: thanks! i thought somebody would tell me that there is no solution. heres what i add process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => results = Convert.ToDouble(e.Data); should i delete process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived); . but what do i do at the static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)?

Comment: i think there is some misunderstanding(my fault anyway). results is not simply console output. there are multiple lines of console output. plus i need to do some filtering before i get the results. is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: You can delete the old `process_OutputDataReceived`. See my edit for how to do more than one thing inside the handler.